# Using WIF & ADFS to retrieve claims about a user

Tags: c#, .net, wif, adfs

**Short Background:** Currently my situation is such that I have a service (WCF) of which I do **NOT** control the WSDL/Interface. When the client calls "Submit" the user passes credientals. I then want to use those credentials to authenticate against ADFS and receive encrypted claims. Once I have these claims back as a RequestSecurityTokenResponse I have the RequestSecurityTokenResponse.SecurityTokenXml available (an encrypted XmlElement). It seems the RequestSecurityTokenResponse.SecurityToken is null (perhaps only one or the other is returned?)

**Note:** Because I do not control the WSDL, I am not forcing the user to authenticate in order to use the service, but rather using the credentials they send with a request to authenticate. This means I am doing this in code rather than in Config. I can post sample code if it is needed.

**Questions:**

1. Does this sound like a reasonable approach given the circumstances?
2. How would I decrypt this XmlElement with the certificate?
3. Should I not encrypt the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around more I was lead to [this](http://zamd.net/2010/03/10/extractsamlassertion/) site which takes care of at least the encryption/decryption questions for me.